# SQLite insert into select distinct from

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to migrate data from an old table to a new table in **SQLite**. The problem is in my new table I have a column unique which was not unique in the old table. I'm looking for the query which makes it possible without dropping sqlite error.

Let's suppose my unique column is col_3 (same column names in both tables)

```
"INSERT INTO [NEW_TABLE] (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) SELECT (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) FROM [OLD_TABLE]"
```

This will throw an error since my old table was accepting duplicated elements in "col_3" and my new table doesn't.

How can I insert data avoiding duplicateds?

**UPDATE**

There's a foreign key in between col_1 and col_3

Comment: It is throwing the same error than using just insert => "UNIQUE constraing failed"

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7g8ayEgSFNZ5juiNTWMzkJ/0

Comment: Yes, you were right! Thanks